# Ruby on Rails, call a function from model in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method in my controller:

```
def create
  p_attr=params[:upload]
  p_attr[:upload] = params[:upload][:upload].first if params[:upload][:arraydb].class == Array
  @upload = Upload.new(p_attr)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @upload.save
      @arraydb.process_name
    end
  end 
end
```

in a model I have another method where I can process the upload that was just saved:

```
def self.process_name 
  update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
  update_attributes(:defined => "no")
end
```

It gives me an error that the method `process_name` is not defined for `Upload`

What is the problem and how can I update the attributes of just saved file in a model from a controller?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't-it's defined for the *class*, not instances.

You're trying to call it on an instance. Make it an instance method.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, methods defined with `self.` before the name are class methods. This means you can only call such methods on the class itself, not on its instances.

This means that:

```
upload = Upload.new()
upload.process_name
```

results in an error

While:

```
Upload.process_name
```

will call the method.

Since what you really want to do is to call `process_name` in instances of the `Upload` class, you can correct your code by removing `self.` from your method definition, resulting in:

```
def process_name
    update_attributes(:user_id => current_user.id)
    update_attributes(:defined => "no")
end
```